# C++ class and friend

Tags: c++, class, friend

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class C
{
private:
    string str;
    friend void func();
};


void func()
{
        str = "Lala";
        cout << str << endl;

}

int main()
{
    func();
}
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work.
In my bigger project I want to acces private variables of a class with a function out of class.
Here I made a class C and made a function func(); to be its friend.But still I can't use it's private variables in function.
What I did wrong and is there a better way to do this?

Comment: On which object is `func` supposed to operate?

Comment: How does it not work?

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't work because `void func();` is not a member function of the class, it's just declared as a friend function to it, meaning it can access the private members.

You have no instance of the `class C`, so you can't possibly refer to any valid `str` variable.

Answer (score 3):

Next time, please also quote the errors you get. In this case, there will be a compile error stating the symbol "str" has not been defined within func().

If you want to access the member str of a class instance of C, you need such an instance, as in:

```
void func(){
    C c;
    c.str = "Lala";
    cout << c.str << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

`func()` is *not* a member function, and it is not receiving any parameter of type `C`, what object is it supposed to operate on?

`func` must either be a member function of `C` (in which case you'll invocate it over an instance of `C`, and `friend` is not necessary), either a function that receives some parameter of type `C` (or create a local `C` object), on which it can work on, even accessing its private fields.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work since str is not defined inside func().
You should have an instance of C.

```
void func()
{
    C foo;
    foo.str = "Lala";
    cout << str << endl;
}
```

If you need to you can pass the C instance as a parameter:

```
void func(C &foo)
{
    foo.str = "Lala";
    cout << str << endl;
}
```

Comment: @soon Meh it has been way too long since I coded in C++.

Answer (score 2):

## The problem

Let's look at your code piece by piece:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
```

Just a short note here: It is a bad idea to use `using namespace std;`.

```
class C
{
private:
    string str;
    friend void func();
};
```

Here you define a class C. You declare that *objects* of this class will contain a string, which is private (i.e. may only be accessed by class members and friends), and you declare the global function `void func()` a friend, that is, it is allowed to access the private members (in this case `str`) of the class `C` and of any object of type `C`. Note that apart from that permission, `func` is in no way related to the class `C`.

```
void func()
{
        str = "Lala";
        cout << str << endl;

}
```

Here you try to assign to a variable `str` which you never declared. Remember that there's no relation of `func` to the class `C` other than that it may access the private members of 
`C` and objects of type `C`. However, there's no object of type `C` in sight, and even if there were, there's nothing to tell the compiler from which object `str` is to be taken, or even that you are speaking about the `str` in `C`. I'll remember you again that `func` is completely independent of `C`, so the code is interpreted the same way as if `C` wouldn't have declared it a friend.

```
int main()
{
    func();
}
```

OK, nothing special here, you're just calling `func`.

## How to fix it

Now, how to fix your code? Well, there are several possibilities:

### Supplying objects

#### Local objects

Since `str` is a member of *objects* of class `C`, you'll need an object of the class. So you could for example do:

```
void func()
{
  C object;
  object.str = "Lala";
  std::cout << object.str << std::endl;
}
```

Here you create a local object in `func`, assign to *that object's* `str` member a value and then outputs it. To see that different objects have different members, you can e.g. write:

```
void func()
{
  C object1, object2;
  object1.str = "Lala";
  object2.str = "Lele";
  std::cout << object1.str << " -- " << object2.str << "\n";
}
```

This outputs `Lala -- Lele` because the first object's `str` member has the value `"Lala"` while the second object's `str` member has the value `"Lele"`.

#### Function arguments

Another option is that you pass the object as argument, e.g.

```
void func(C object)
{
  std::cout << object.str << " -- ";
  object.str = "Lele";
  std::cout << object.str << " -- ";
}

int main()
{
  C main_object;
  main_object.str = "Lala";
  func(main_object);
  std::cout << object.str << std::endl;
}
```

This prints `Lala -- Lele -- Lala`.

What happens here is that in `main` an object is created, whose `str` member is assigned the valeu `"Lala"`. On call to `func`, a *copy* of that object is created, which you then access from `func`. Since it's a copy, it initially also contains the same value `"Lala", which`func`then outputs. Then the assignment in`func`changes the`str`member *of that copy* to`"Lele"`and outputs that. The original object is not affected as the output in`main` shows.

So you see, there can be several objects, and it is crucial that you say the `str` member of *which* object you want to access.

Now if you do not intend to change the object in the called function, making a copy is just a waste of time, therefore you can also pass it as a *reference to const*:

```
void func(C const& object)
{
  std::cout << object.str << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  C main_object;
  main_object.str = "Lala";
  func(main_object);
}
```

The argument `C const&` says "I want to directly access the object the caller gives me, but I promise not to change it." The "directly access" part is denoted by the `&`, and the "I promise not to change it" is denoted by the `const`. The compiler actually checks that you hold your promise and don't try to change it (that is, if in `func` you tried to do `object.str = "Lele"`, the compiler would complain (there are ways to tell the compiler to shut up about that, but you shouldn't do that; just keep your promises). However note that this applies again *only to that specific object*; for example, the following code is completely OK:

```
void func(C const& object)
{
  C another_object;
  another_object.str = "Lele";
  std::cout << object.str << " -- " << another_object.str << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  C main_object;
  main_object.str = "Lala";
  func(main_object);
}
```

This gives no error and prints `Lala -- Lele` because you're dealing again with different objects.

Of course there may be the case that you *do* want to change the object you are passed. Then you can just use `&` without `const`:

```
void func(C& object)
{
  std::cout << object.str << " -- ";
  object.str = "Lele";
  std::cout << object.str << " -- ";
}

int main()
{
  C main_object;
  main_object.str = "Lala";
  func(main_object);
  std::cout << object.str << std::endl;
}
```

This prints `Lala -- Lele -- Lele`.

Now you again directly access the object passed as argument from `main`, but this time, you don't promise that you don't change it, and indeed you *do* change it. The output from `main` demonstrates that indeed `main_object` was changed.

### Making the variable a static member

Now, there's the possibility that you *really* want there to only ever be one `str` in `C`, not a separate one for each object of that type. If you are absolutely positive that this is what you want, then you can make `str` a static member of the class:

```
class C
{
private:
  static std::string str; // note the keyword "static" here
  friend void func();
};

std::string C::str; // You have to have an extra definition for class static variables!
```

Now you can access `str` without having an object of `C` available. However note that you *still* need to tell the compiler inside `func` that you want to access the `str` inside `C`:

```
void func()
{
  C::str = "Lala";
  std::cout << C::str << std::endl;
}
```

You can also access the variable on object *as if* it were a member of that object. However be aware that this does *not* mean that different objects still have their own `str`. For example, with the changed class definition, we will gett different behaviour for the code from above:

```
void func()
{
  C object1, object2;
  object1.str = "Lala";
  object2.str = "Lele";
  std::cout << object1.str << " -- " << object2.str << "\n";
}
```

Now we will get the output `Lele -- Lele` because there's only one `str`, which does not depend on the object (the syntax `object1.str` in this case is misleading in that respect; actually here it means "the `str` defined for the *type* of `object1`, that is, `C`").

Answer (score 1):

```
void func(C* object)
{
        object->str = "Lala";
        cout << object->str << endl;

}
```

Since `func` is not a member of the class, so you can't call it like `object.func()`. Thus the function won't know which object of the class you wish to change. So you have to explicitly pass the object pointer to the function. Use a reference would also do.

Or you can declare `str` as `static`. But static member will make all instances of the class share the same value.

Comment: Since the OP is a complete beginner I believe it might be useful to explain in this answer why exactly you used a pointer. Also why are not using a reference?

Comment: see my comment. and it wasn't me btw.